# Pass post variable to url

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i pass the post variable to segment url? i can read it from url but i can't set it...
What i have so far : `$route['shop/find/(:any)']= "shop/find/$1";` on routes,my find.php on views, and my function `

```
function find()
    {
            $this->load->model('shopFront/find');
            $this->load->model('currency');
            $this->load->model('shopFront/calculate');
            $this->load->model('shop/proccess');
            $data = $this->commondatashop->general();
            $inputSlug = $this->input->post('findSlug');
            $data['tofind'] = $inputSlug;
            $data['cartInfo'] = $this->shopcart;
            $data['Currency'] = $this->currency;
            $data['Calculate'] = $this->calculate;
            $data['Proccess'] = $this->proccess;
            $data['title'] = "1.4.U Shop | Find";
            $finder = $this->find;
            $data['finderservice'] = $finder;
            $data['user_id'] = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
            $data['user_name'] = $this->session->userdata('user_name');
            $this->load->view('shop/top/topNew',$data);
            $this->load->view('shop/content/find',$data);

            //footer
            $curravailable = $this->calculate->getCurrencies();
            if ( $curravailable !== false )
            {
                $data['currencies'] = $curravailable;
            }
            else
            {
                $data['currencies'] = 'none';
            }
            $this->load->view('shop/footer',$data);


    }`
```

How can i post the variable to the find()function with url segment?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have find accept an argument with a default

```
function find($i=0) {
  //$i is whatever is in the URL or defaults to 0
```

Comment: Yes but i post to find and the find function redirects to the find viewer and the url stays mysite/find instead of mysite/find/item

Comment: if you post to `yoursite/controller/find`, you are not going to get that variable, you need to post to `yourside/controller/find/id` or send POST data with your post which instead of collecting from params, you would use CI's input class. i.e. $i = `$this->input->post('post_var_name');`

Comment: so i need to change this 
<?php echo form_open('shop/find','find'); ?>
<input type="submit" name="find" value="" />
<input type="text" name="findSlug" />
<?php echo form_close();  ?>

with $this->input->post instead of submit?

Comment: turning <?php echo form_open('shop/find','find'); to  <?php echo form_open('shop/find/id','find'); it just goes to /find/id it doens't replace it with the text i put

Answer (score 0):

In your view:

```
echo form_open('/shop/find');
echo form_input('findSlug','');
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
```

Controller:

```
$data[slug] = $this->input->post('findSlug');
```

You need to load form helper too